# Where are the logs for Kaleo workflow error: An error occurred in the workflow engine

Tags: workflow, liferay-6

I would like to know where to see more details on this Kaleo workflow error: An error occurred in the workflow engine.

I modified the single-approver-definition.xml to assign tasks to approvers depending on the category of the web content but I am unable to find the error. I also used Liferay's categorisation definition but am getting the same error.

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/webs/kaleo-web/docroot/WEB-INF/src/META-INF/definitions/category-specific-definition.xml

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<workflow-definition xmlns="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0 http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-workflow-definition_6_1_0.xsd">
```

in header code xml. It resolves the problem.